# installing waterline ORM with mssql on sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I cant seem to figure out how to install waterline orm using the sails-mssql adapter, I have installed waterline and sails-mssql and  this is how config/datastore.js looks:

module.exports.datastores = {

default: {
    adapter: require('sails-mssql'),
     url: 'mssql://sonkozo:#Coding301!@localhost:3306/mydb',

},

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to :  `adapter: require('sails-mssql')`

you only need to :  `adapter: 'sails-mssql'`

Comment: thanks Rami for the answer but I ended up using sails-sql instead it worked.

Comment: [sails-sql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-sql) includes support for mssql, mysql, and soon postgresql - taking over for those three sails orm adapters for waterline.